# Does Peggy's speech in the Tokyo ESP previews follow some pattern?

Tags: japanese-language, tokyo-esp

The Tokyo ESP next-episode previews are pretty simple. They're just a mostly static screen on which the title of the next episode appears, and Peggy (the penguin) says something which seems to be the usual cute-sounding gibberish noises.

[image: Episode 6 preview]

I noticed that Peggy seems to always say the same number of syllables as the title, and with a similar rhythm to how it would be spoken in Japanese. That makes me suspect that Peggy is actually saying the title of the next episode, but changes the syllables based on some pattern. Repeated syllables (like in the episode 6 preview shown above) are pronounced the same as far as I can tell, which seems to support this theory. Looking at a few English-language sources, I couldn't find any discussions of this, or even anyone suggesting that there might be some pattern.

**Does Peggy's speech in the next-episode previews follow some set pattern?** (As a bonus, does the pattern also apply to Peggy's speech in the episodes proper?)